# Is there any way to use reflex to convert between character case?

Tags: c++, unicode, lex

[RE-flex](https://github.com/Genivia/RE-flex) is a pretty neat unicode aware version of flex, which is awesome if you've used flex before (I have :-).

We're currently undergoing a major redesign for all of our products; the main goal is to support unicode from day 1 in the new implementations -- we don't really need to do a lot of stuff; beyond knowing the case of a "letter" and what a whitespace character is, we need to, sometimes, convert a character from lower case to upper case or vice versa. On top of that we also need a regular expression engine that allows backtracking (we can work around this, but it makes our lives a bit easier).

RE-flex will let us do first two easily and it allows us to use the C++ `std::regex` as the engine, which does support backtracking (we haven't tested this, so -- if this causes any problems with cases please let me know).

The only alternative we can find is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). We would like to avoid using this since we have to deploy on some very limited platforms where the footprint of ICU is a bit of a problem. We've talked about how we can reduce it to something manageable, but we'd rather not do the work if we can avoid it.

So, is RE-flex a viable part of the solution to our problems, or are we forced to using ICU? If we can use RE-flex, how do we use it to convert cases?

Comment: You might have to rethink the design since you cannot always convert between cases on a character-level in Unicode. That's why ICU has two variants for changing case:
http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings

Comment: As I suspect... not a trivial thing to do.